# Phenomenon of talking apple

Tags: home-experiment

Recently I noticed something weird when took a metal bowl with a few apples out of the fridge and left them to get warm. After a while I heard a distinct sound in the form of sharp clicks approx. every 10-15 seconds within the half an hour or more. At first I thought it was the bowl dropping deformation after cooling. But in fact it was an apple. Its diameter was about 5 cm. After I cut the apple next morning there were two seeds inside each cell. So I'm wondering what the physics occurred behind this phenomenon? What's the nature of the sounds? Btw, it was the only one apple.